# Sort an int array in what is Closest to them

Tags: java, sorting

How to sort a array in what is closest to current num e.g

```
int NumList[] = {55,80,67,44,90,65}
```

to

```
int NumList[] = {55,65,67,80,90,44}
```

I tried doing it to a modified bubble sort but fails

```
for(int i=1; i<NumList.length; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            dist = Math.abs(NumList[i]-NumList[i-1]);
            for (int j = i +1; j < NumList.length; j++) {
                newdist=Math.abs(NumList[i]-NumList[j]);
                System.out.println(dist + ">" + newdist); 
                if(dist > newdist)
                {
                    temp = NumList[i];
                    NumList[i] = NumList[j];
                    NumList[j] = temp;
                    tempdist=newdist;
                    if(dist>tempdist){
                        dist=tempdist;
                    }
                    System.out.println("yes");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("no");
            }
```

The first int in the array wont change position because it will be the reference point

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "Closest"

Comment: Also please define "fails".

Comment: I want to sort of randomized numbers  to their distance to each other eg distance from 55->65 (15) is lower then 55->44 (16)

Comment: using my code wont sort them properly

Comment: store the first element of the original array, sort the array, find the index of first element (n) , rotate array 'n' times

Answer (score 0):

Put the result of your algorithm into another array:

```
Var orderedArray = [] ;
for(int i=1; i<NumList.length; i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            dist = Math.abs(NumList[i]-NumList[i-1]);
            for (int j = i +1; j < NumList.length; j++) {
                newdist=Math.abs(NumList[i]-NumList[j]);
                System.out.println(dist + ">" + newdist); 
                if(dist < newdist)
                {
                    orderedArray.push(numList(i));

  }
                    System.out.println("yes");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("no");
            }
```